# Cannot Obeserve LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to update the values in an EditText by observing a LiveData from a ViewModel.

Here is the FRAGMENT in which I am trying to update the values of my EditText:

```
private var qnaQuestionData: String = "TEST VALUE"

private val communicationViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(
            MyProfileEditSharedViewModel::class.java
        )
    }

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        communicationViewModel.question.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {data ->
                data.let { qnaQuestionData = it }
        })

        et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)

}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
class MyProfileEditSharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val question: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
}
```

When I run this code, the value of my EditText is set to "TEST VALUE" which means that the LiveData was never observed. How can I fix this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
private val communicationViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(
            MyProfileEditSharedViewModel::class.java
        )
    }
```

to

```
private val communicationViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(
            MyProfileEditSharedViewModel::class.java
        )
    }
```

Solved the problem.
The official docs told me to change `this` to `requireActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

Move the call `et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)` to the observer:

```
communicationViewModel.question.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { data ->
    qnaQuestionData = data
    et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)
})

et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)
```

Comment: Are you updating your `question` variable int `MyProfileEditSharedViewModel` class?

Comment: Yes! However, even if `question`(LiveData) was not being updated, I still would not get "TEST VALUE"(initial value) in my edit text...

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check. If you want to set a default text to `et_question` you can call `et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)` like you did before.

Answer (score 1):

> I would change your MyProfileEditSharedViewModel  to be like this

```
class MyProfileEditSharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val question: MutableLiveData<String>  = MutableLiveData()
}
```

> and your fragment should be like this

```
class someFragment(): Fragment() {

    private var qnaQuestionData: String = "TEST VALUE"
    private val communicationViewModel
        get() = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(MyProfileEditSharedViewModel::class.java)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)

        communicationViewModel.question.postValue("This Message will Show") //<------- for testing
        communicationViewModel.question.observe(this, Observer {
            qnaQuestionData = it
            et_question.setText(qnaQuestionData)
        })
    }
}
```